# Maven not storing artifacts in the directory specified by localRepository in settings.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

I am using apache-maven-3.2.3

It is located at C:\java\apache-maven-3.2.3

The settings.xml file is located C:\java\apache-maven-3.2.3\conf\settings.xml

Inside that settings.xml file, I have the following defined:

```
<localRepository>C:/java/maven_repo</localRepository>
```

I have windows environment variables defined:

> - M2_HOME=C:\java\apache-maven-3.2.3
> - M2=%M2_HOME%\bin
> - PATH environment variable includes %M2%

I have configures my STS (Eclipse) to use the external Maven installation at C:\java\apache-maven-3.2.3

My STS Maven-->Installations shows that the global settings are: C:\java\apache-maven-3.2.3\conf\settings.xml

My STS Maven-->User Settings shows that the local repository from merged and global settings is: C:\java\maven_repo

There is NO settings.xml at C:/Users/[myuser]/.m2

In fact, I remove the entire .m2 folder at C:/Users/[myuser]/.m2 to be sure

**However**, When I do a Maven update through STS, it is still downloading artifacts to the default .m2 directory at: C:/Users/[myuser]/.m2/repository

My Eclipse project is also showing the Maven Dependencies are found in C:/Users/[myuser]/.m2/repository

Can anyone tell me why? What have I done wrong? Why wont it use the local repository at c:/java/maven_repo ?

Comment: Could you please clarify why you edited the global settings.xml inside the Maven installation instead of defining one in `$USER_HOME/.m2`?  What you're attempting is not the typical way a local repo location is defined.

Comment: We are standardizing everyone's development environments in the team with the  same folder structure etc. So we have a "customized" Maven installation zip file which all new team members will simply extract into their c:/Java folder, and this Maven installation has a settings.xml which is pre-configured to our environment. We basically want everything contained in the same folder structure, not scattered about in personal "user" folders etc.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I will change the default local repository folder from default **.m2** to another more meaningful name, for example, **maven-repo**.

Find **{M2_HOME}\conf\setting.xml**, update localRepository to something else.

```
  <settings>
      <!-- localRepository
       | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
       |
       | Default: ~/.m2/repository
      <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
      -->

    <localRepository>D:/maven_repo</localRepository>
```

**Done, your new Maven local repository is now changed to D:/maven_repo.**

Comment: this worked worked for me, this is from MKYONGs tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have managed to get this to work in Eclipse is to also set the user settings file in Window-->Preferences-->Maven-->User Settings to the same as the global settings: C:\java\apache-maven-3.2.3\conf\settings.xml

But I would imagine that leaving that field blank should take the settings from the global settings.xml, but for some reason it doesn't. So if I leave that user settings field blank, the localRepositorty from global settings.xml does not apply.

However, if I run Maven outside eclipse, it works as expected.